# <input type="hidden" functionality issue

Tags: javascript, html

Iv'e got a split menu system using javascript. Because im requesting information, im using the input tags.

I dont want checkboxes, textboxes, radio butons etc interfering with the design. So i tried the hidden input type. Keeps the design, but keeps reverting back to female, or the first one on the list, if nothing was selected. For example. I select male and submit. Male selection enters my code. Now, i do something else and click submit, and the below code reverts back to female with out me say so. It dosent do thise with check or radio, so why does it do this with "hidden".

Also, what input type should i use if i dont want to upset function or design, or how else can i go about this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown  a").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown ul").toggle();
        });

        });                                
        $(".dropdown ul li a").click(function() {
            var text = $(this).html();
            $(".dropdown a span").html(text);
            $(".dropdown ul").hide();
            $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
        });

        function getSelectedValue(id) {
            return $("#" + id).find("li a span.value").html();
        }

        $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                $(".dropdown ul").hide();
        });

    });

<form action="" method="get">   
 <div class="sort">
<ul> 
  <li id="sample" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Gender |<span>{{ gender }}</span></a>

    <ul><li><a href="#"><input id="radio1" name="Gender" value="Female"/>Female</a>
            <a href="#"><input id="radio2" name="Gender" value="Male"/>Male</a>
            <a href="#"><input id="radio3" name="Gender" value="Both Sexes"/>Both Sexes</a>

    </li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Revert back. Is there any other way to revert? - Grammar Nazi

Answer (score 3):

You are using these completely wrong. Clicking the A tags is changing nothing at all here. Why would you expect it to?

You should use the radio button, but apply styles to it properly. Or reduce your hidden fields to just one, and use Javascript to change its value. That's a bad design, though, because the user is given *no* indication what they have selected.

Comment: I don't see why just showing the radios is "interfering with design" (OPs description). What's a link indicate? Not a "selection". Maybe there's more than shown in the question, but it's seemingly a bad approach. I agree.

Comment: What a convoluted mess. My answer stands. Your additional code is actually making it *worse* by adding yet another instance of the already duplicated hidden field.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your hidden input fields are all named the same thing<s>, therefore the last one defined will always take effect</s>.

**Edit:** depending on the server language handling the request, the first, last, or entire list may be effective. PHP, for example, will only recognize the last value submitted.

Comment: All the values will be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `radio` type inputs, but you can use `style="display:none"` to remove them from view.

Comment: Nope adding the style="display:none" stuffs it up

Comment: Styling them that way prevents their selection, perhaps except by scripting.