# Adding form function to a menu

Tags: javascript, html

I asked this question [<input type="hidden" functionality issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903987/input-type-hidden-functionality-issue) a couple of days ago and was basically told its a mess your doing it wrong and style it properly. Thing is i dont know how so ill ask the same question a different way. I ask again cause im about 10hrs into this now, and no closer to a solution.

I want to add a form function that gets the information. Say

```
<form action="" method="get">
```

My belief is i have to add an input tab somewhere to actually get the info

```
<input type="....
```

And round it off with

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

to submit it.

How do i incorporate this into the below code to add the functionality without losing the style. I havent add style/css section as i didnt think it would it matter to the question at hand.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown  a").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown ul").toggle();
        });

        });                                
        $(".dropdown ul li a").click(function() {
            var text = $(this).html();
            $(".dropdown a span").html(text);
            $(".dropdown ul").hide();
            $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
        });

        function getSelectedValue(id) {
            return $("#" + id).find("li a span.value").html();
        }

        $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                $(".dropdown ul").hide();
        });

    });
 <form action="" method="get"> 
 <div class="sort">
<ul> 
  <li id="sample" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Gender |<span>Both sexes</span></a>

    <ul><li><a href="#">Male<span class="value">Male</span></a>
            <a href="#">Female<span class="value">Female</span></a>
            <a href="#">Both Sexes<span class="value">Both Sexes</span></a>

    </li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: you can declare <div> element under <form> and use <input type="submit"> in same form.

Comment: hmm, let me see if your right

Comment: how you tried can you share that code?

Comment: "..without losing the style" of what? I do not understand the question.

Comment: changed code to show kiran what i did.

Comment: well, akonsu, i can get function if i add say "<a href='#'><input type="radio" value="Female"/>Female</a>" but then i get a radio circle. Thus the look and style of the menu has changed.

Comment: do you want the links to submit the form? is that what you are asking?

Comment: i think so yes. the above answer i gave you does this but as i say, i lose style.

Comment: it seems that you are not sure what you want. can you describe the problem in human language without showing any code? here i my understanding: the user has to chose between three options: male, female and both. to do that the user clicks on one of the links. end of story. correct?

Comment: There's a seperate table displaying information. I want the user to sort the information via a number of options, one of them being by sex. He hovers the cursor the Gender menu. To the right pops up 3 options, Male, Female, Both Sexes. He clicks one. Nothing is suppose to happen yet. Only when he clicks a submit button, will his selection be sent to the server side, and bang his table is sorted by his selection. If i dont add "<input type="radio" value="Female"/>" nothing happens. If i do a radio button appears next the menu selections, which is not what i want.

Comment: I would have a form on the page with a single hidden field. Then I would have this menu with three choices. I would attach a javascript event handler to each item's onclick event and in the event handler I would set the hidden field to a specific value. say, 1, 2, or 3. this field would be submitted when the user clicks the submit button.

Comment: Could you give me an example or link on how to do this. The above code was copied from a menu examples site. I.ve been playing around trying to try get it to do what i specifically want but cant figure it out.

Comment: here is some code: http://jsbin.com/izaruv/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a form on the page with a single hidden field. Then I would have this menu with three choices. I would attach a javascript event handler to each item's onclick event and in the event handler I would set the hidden field to a specific value. say, 1, 2, or 3. this field would be submitted when the user clicks the submit button.

here is the code: http://jsbin.com/izaruv/2